# OpenSans font not working in iOS simulator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, fonts, uilabel

I'd like to use the [OpenSans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans) font on a `UILabel`, but it's not showing up in the iOS simulator. All that appears is the default system font. I have:

1) Added files to project + selected to copy to app folder.

2) Added to Info.plist.

[image: info.plist]

3) Xcode automatically added all fonts to my build phases folder.

4) Cleaned the project + built it again.

And it still doesn't show up! In my code, I have this:

```
self.itemPrice = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(230.0, 30.0, 75.0, 30.0)];
        self.itemPrice.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
        self.itemPrice.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-ExtraBold" size:13.0f];
        self.itemPrice.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        self.itemPrice.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [Formatters formatPrice:self.item.price]];
        [self.slidingDetailScrollView addSubview:self.itemPrice];
```

Anyone know what is causing this bizarre bug?

Comment: Note that `fontWithName` requires the font name, not the file name. The font name could be "OpenSans ExtraBold" or similar, you can check that if you open the font in the "Font Book" application.

Comment: might be you are typing wrong font name , print all configured fonts list and check name twice.!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fixed it, it was because of this minor error.

```
self.itemPrice.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"OpenSans-Extrabold" size:13.0f];
```

`Extrabold`, not `ExtraBold`. I opened up Font Viewer, as recommended, and it showed that under `PostScript Name`.

I have now used `#define`'s to place a font string name in there and use that throughout my application to avoid user error and literal strings in the middle of my code.

Comment: lol I ran into the exact same problem while trying to use OpenSans-SemiBold XD