# ios simulator won't load fonts

Tags: css, xcode, fonts, ios-simulator

I've got two fonts in my application. 
When I test my application in the ios simulator (xcode) the first font (rockwell) doesn't show anymore. (but in the browser it does) 
The second font (san francisco text) has different font-weights. Same story, in the browser it all works fine but when I check it in the ios simulator the font-weight is whether light or very bold.

Comment: I use webfontkit generator to import my fonts, that's the difference.

Comment: may be this will help https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/79071/custom-font-issues and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16636196/opensans-font-not-working-in-ios-simulator